# 12.04 can't detect my D-Link Airtel Net Setter

Tags: software-center

I had purchased a D-Link Net Setter and insert a Airtel Prepaid Sim in it. I am using it in Windows 7 but it can't be detected in 12.04 LTS. I created one mobile broadband connection using a connection wizard, after that, it was not detected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the D-Link Net Setter as an USB drive in Ubuntu. There will be a file with `.deb` extension similar to `dlinkmodem.deb`.
2. Double click on it and it will guide you through installing it via the **Ubuntu Software Centre**.
3. When it has installed, scroll down in **Ubuntu Software Centre** to find a command that you need to run in terminal.
4. Open a terminal window (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type that command. Then the modem should now work.